# Why doesn't Ubuntu (and Mint) install a boot sequence

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, boot, grub2, boot-loader

I've tried to install a new Linux operating system and I've tried different flavors (x)ubuntu, Mint etc. With and without encryption, with and without LVM, but I'll always get the same error.

When rebooting after an error free installation, my PC will boot up and skip along the the boot order:

1. CD
2. USB
3. HDD
4. Network boot
5. FDD

It will skip to Network boot and try to find something there. Once I removed 4. from the list it will give the following error:

> Error 1962: No operating  system found. Press any key to repeat boot
>   sequence.

Edit:
I did what Web-E recommends here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/159469/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-installation , but the problem still exists. Here is the resulting Logfile:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12543053/
2nd attempt:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12543267/

Comment: You need to provide more details about your setup. What is the hardware (particularly disks)? Where do you install GRUB (or any other bootloader of your choice)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to know the exact model of my hard drive? I don't pick where or which bootloader to install. I just pick "delete previous installations and use whole harddrive" and with all previous installations the rest was done by Ubuntu.

Comment: No, the hard drive model does not seem to be relevant. What I'm asking is your setup. Do you have a single HDD or a few of them? What version of the system are you installing? If it is 64-bit, is your computer 64-bit as well?

Comment: A single HDD and both the OS and my PC are 64bit

Comment: OK, next question: is it marked with a "Windows 8 compatible" or similar sticker? Please ensure that in your UEFI settings you have disabled any of Secureboot, Fastboot, Quickboot, Fast Startup or similar as these may get in the way.

Comment: I removed all stickers, but I believe my Computer is to old for UEFI and I've had Linux running on this machine for a couple of years. This problem has only come up recently. Maybe since linux has adapted to UEFI, but I can't tell for sure.